# C integer/float array strange behavior

Tags: c, arrays

Okay so i was just fooling around making random programs and seeing their outputs to understanding how things work and i noticed a strange thing about integer/float arrays. Unlike char array the '\0' character is not stored directly after the last entered element into the array. In integer array it is stored two elements after the last element and in float its four elements. Here's the code to demonstrate this strange fact. Please help me understand why this happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(int* x)
{
    while ( *(x) != '\0' )
    {
        printf("%i ",*x);
        ++x;
    }
} 

void foo1(float* x)
{
    while ( *(x) != '\0')
    {
        printf("%.1f ",*x);
        ++x;
    }
} 

void foo2(char* x)
{
    while( *(x) != '\0' )
    {
        printf("%c",*x);
        ++x;
    }
} 

int main(void)
{
    int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    float b[4] = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4};
    char name[] = "Muneeb";

    foo(a);
    printf("\n\n");

    foo1(b);
    printf("\n\n");

    foo2(name);
    return 0;
  }
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 -12345677723 -1623562626
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -0.0 -1.3
```

Comment: `*(x) != '\0'` when `x` is a `float *` makes no sense. At best it compares with the 0 value...

Comment: Please include the output in your question, as text, not as a link to an image of the text.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisFabre i want to know how many elements are there before \0 thats why i used while *x !=\0

Comment: @KeithThompson Okay sir will do from now on

Comment: What makes you think that all arrays are zero-terminated? It is a specialty of char arrays initialised by a string constant. Guessing at your not shown output, you are accessing beyond the array and invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Yunnosch So float/int arrays don't end with \0?

Comment: _So float/int arrays don't end with \0?_ Correct

Comment: Maybe you are confusing `NUL`-terminated strings and arrays. String literals like `"ABC"` are finalized with `'\0'`. Arrays like `{'A', 'B', 'C'}` are not. (zero-terminated strings are special types of Arrays.)

Comment: @JojOatXGME so is there a way to know exactly how many numbers user has entered in an array except for initializing an array to zero prior to its usage and then using while( arr[i] != 0) ?

Comment: @Muneeb use a *counter* variable. Or if the array is static then please *do* add the 0 / 0.0 there explicitly.

Comment: `int a[4] = {1,2,3,4}; float b[4] = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4};` --> `int a[] = {1,2,3,4, 0}; float b[] = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4, 0};`

Comment: The 0 terminator only applies to *strings*, not to arrays in general.  If you need to keep track of how many elements in an array have been set, you need to use a separate counter.

Comment: @JohnBode elaboration on the "separate counter" please.

Comment: You can say an `int length = 4` when you create the array, and then whenever you call a function taking an array, also give it a length parameter.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala A lot of times an array might be static but have `0` as an internal value. Terminating it with a zero often does not help in this case. However, a static array has a static size, and just storing its size will always work.

Comment: @Muneeb: Use a separate variable to keep track of how many elements in the array have been set.

Answer (score 10):

In general, there is no zero element after the end of an array. You cannot assume there is; this kind of code could just as easily segfault. You are finding a zero which is only there by coincidence.

In `char` arrays in particular, this rule is the same. However, a literal string like `"Hello, world!"` is actually one `char` longer than what you’d get just by counting characters. This is [equivalent to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) an unmodifiable `char[13]` of `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '\0'}`. A lot of library functions for working with `char`s expect a terminating `'\0'`; no such expectation usually exists for other types of arrays and you need to pass the length explicitly.

Also note that your `*(x) != '\0'` [treats](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) the `'\0'` as an `int` or `float` zero, and is equivalent to `*x != 0` or `*x != 0.0f` (for the different types of `x` in the different functions). If you had stored an actual 0 in one of the arrays, it would have just counted to that.

---

Since there is no special sentinel convention for `int` or `float` arrays (because `0` and `0.0f` are usually perfectly reasonable values to put in the array), you should create a separate [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) variable to keep track of the array’s length. Then, if you ever need to create a function acting on an array, you can also give it a `length` parameter and have it iterate up to that. For example:

```
void foo(int* x, size_t length)
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("%i ", x[i]);
    }

}
```

(I use [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) here because it typically represents the size of structures in memory).

Then you can call this with `foo(a, 4);`. If you need a variable-sized array, you can create a `size_t a_length` variable when you create `a`, and update it whenever `a`’s size changes.

You might even want to do this with `char` arrays sometimes, such as if you have binary data which might contain zero bytes, or because scanning for the end of the string takes time and you usually don’t need to look at each character.

Comment: Detail: "converts the `'\0'` into an `int` "` --> `'\0'` is an `int ` in C, no conversion needed.

Comment: Thank you sir i got that . :)

Comment: @chux Oops, yes, I keep forgetting that rule because it is not at all what I expect.

Comment: That is what distinguishes the `char` array from the string. The latter is a `char` array which is terminated with a `'\0'`. You can implement a similar sentinel in any type of array instead of passing its length, you would have to implement that yourself, but with the `char` array, library functions will treat it as a string, when properly terminated.

Comment: @Muneeb A while ago I updated my answer to add a section on what you can do instead; I forgot to comment on it then.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing a *character array* with a *character string*.  In C, strings are not a specific data type; they are implemented using *character arrays*.  The end of a string is indicated by a NUL terminator, but end of the string is not necessarily the end of the array which may be larger, and a *character array* need not represent string at all.

Your observation that other array types have zero terminators (past the end of the array or otherwise) is a false conclusion - the zeroes you have observed in *proximity* to the end are purely coincidental.